# Dispatching to the correct reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm studying the todo redux tutorial. I'm lost though regarding how a dispatch gets sent to the correct reducer since this example combines reducers. How does redux know to send the return value from `setVisibilityFilter` to the `visibilityFilter` reducer?

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

```
export const setVisibilityFilter = (filter) => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
    filter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}
```

Perhaps its getting sent to all reducers by design.

Comment: this video series made by the Redux author may help you understand Redux more. https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as dispatching to a certain reducer. Every time you dispatch an action, *all* reducer functions are executed. The only way to make sure the right piece of code is executed is to make sure the name of the action type is unique, and is present exactly in one reducer among all.

This is why the latest fashion is Redux Modules, where you name every action type with a long string that consists of module name and action type name. Check out [ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) for example.

Comment: More specifically: when you dispatch, the ***single root reducer function*** is executed.  That root reducer may delegate some of the work to other functions, in which case it's up to the root reducer to determine when and how to call them.  The `combineReducers` utility does specifically call all of the "slice reducers" that were passed in, to give them a chance to respond.

Comment: I am very new to redux, and when I was trying to understand how the actions and the reducers work together, it came to my mind that the action executes all reducers or how else it knows which reducer to use. 

@rishat Now you have said what is in your answer above, how does that affect the performance? or it doesn't?

Comment: I haven’t measured the impact on performance, but could intuitively tell that a bigger app that needs a bigger Redux store feels slower, sometimes considerably. I’m not sure to which extent it’s Redux’s impact though, I’d assume not much, because Redux itself isn’t responsible for, say, DOM updates that can be quite costly. Plus, the bigger the app, the harder it is to keep it optimized for performance.

Answer (score 4):

Dispatcher does not know who will get the actions nor does he care. The dispatchers job is only to **dispatch** actions. Now on the other side reducers choose to **listen** to whatever action that comes.

In other words the Dispatcher is just like a speaker, it just gets data and shouts it out. and reducers (in their switch statement or whatever control you're implementing in them) choose which action to react to.